# TFS 2015 to TFS 2017 migration advices

Tags: tfs, migration

What would you recommend or what is the official recommendation of Microsoft regarding migration path after pre-production (test) upgrade?

is it to do an In-Place Upgrade? or is it to do a database migration to a new hardware? Need this information for one of my customers.

The second question is, let's say I choose the second approach and make a production upgrade moving the databases to new hard, do I have a rollback if something goes wrong? or the old environment becomes unusable once I make a production upgrade (remember I am using new hard/VMs)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's completely based on your requirements. If you want to use the old hardware then you can do In-Place upgrade, if your want to migrate to new hardware then just do the database migration.

- **In-Place upgrade:**

  Please note that you **cannot simply rollback for In-Place upgrade** if something goes wrong. So backup the databases first.

  > **Expect the best, prepare for the worst.**
  >
  > While we put a lot of effort into ensuring that TFS upgrades are
  >   highly reliable, it always makes sense to prepare for the case where
  >   something goes wrong. The single most important step you can take here
  >   is to ensure you have a complete and consistent set of [**database
  >   backups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan?view=tfs-2018).
  >
  > **If you're upgrading in place (not moving to new hardware), consider
  >   doing a [dry run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/pre-production?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2018) of your upgrade in a pre-production
  >   environment.**
  >
  > ***Source here:  [Upgrade TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started?view=tfs-2018).***

  You can reference this article to do the upgrade:

  [In-place upgrade to TFS 2017 RTW (Release To Web) with Reporting and SharePoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/12/19/in-place-upgrade-to-tfs-2017-rtw-release-to-web-with-reporting-and-sharepoint/)
- **Migrate to new hardware:**

  Migration will be more flexible and safe, the old environment will still available, it will not be affected if the migration failed. So in my opinion if you have new hardware, then it should be better to do the migration.

  Please see [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2015) for details.

Please note that whether it is in-place or migration, it must match the [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements?view=vsts) first for each TFS version. And never forget to **Backup the databases** for both of them.

Comment: Andy, selecting PRODUCTION UPGRADE on the wizard isn't really necessary only when you are doing an in-place upgrade? 
When you are running on new hardware don't you always have to do the tasks that a PRE-PROD makes? like remaps? I don't see the need to select production upgrade when you are using new hard. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @AndrésG For In-Place upgrade just download the latest version of TFS and setup directly, it will guide you to updage. Pre-production is not necessary for migratiing to new hardware, but remap DB is necessary, just exactly follow the steps mentioned in this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2015

Comment: Andy, I understand what you are saying, but if I am migrating to new hardware both the App Tier and SQL (and Reporting) doing the tasks that the pre-prod wizard does isn't the correct path? sorry, I need to understand the difference in doing this on new hardware: 

1) doing pre-prod on new hard with restored DBs
2) doing prod on new hard with restored DBs